# How to show progress bar in different colors for the rows using prime ng progress bar in angular2

Tags: angular, primeng

[image: Progress bar]

i have list of data, progress bar is displaying but i need  those progress bar to be with different colors,. I tried with ng-class also but didnt work.

HTML:

```
<td><p-progressBar width="100" [value]="statusDisplay.progressValue" [ngClass]="{'progressBar-green': statusDisplay.progressValue > 50}"></p-progressBar></td>
```

Comment: add !important in progressBar-green class

Answer (score 0):

As I looked [at the code](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/progressbar/progressbar.ts#L22) of p-progressBar component, it seems like you can pass `styleClass` property binding to bind custom class to `p-progressBar`

```
<td>
  <p-progressBar width="100" [value]="statusDisplay.progressValue" 
    [styleClass]="getStyleClass(statusDisplay)"> 
  </p-progressBar>
</td>

// you can have your own logic for class.
getStyleClass (statusDisplay) {
    return statusDisplay.progressValue > 50 ? 'progressBar-green': ''
}
```

**OR**

Other way around would be using `style` attribute like demonstrated [in docs](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/progressbar)

Comment: Thanks for response, its not working as i expected, i need different colors for lists of progress bar

Comment: i have pasted that image, i need 3 different colrs for tht

Comment: sorry, i am not getting how i wanted, it is displaying as i posted in image

Comment: @Bhrungarajni did you see my updated answer :) you have to add your logic in `getStyleClass` function

Comment: what do you mean by didn't work? can you add stackblitz of the same?

Comment: @Bhrungarajni can you provide a stackblitz with what you have tried so far?